# Является ли утверждение x[0] равно null истинным после выполнения данной строки?

Tags: java, массивы, null

int []x = new int[25];
Вопрос простой.

Comment: `int` - тип значения. Он не может равняться `null`, так как `null` есть по своей природе *ссылка*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если массив создается таким образом, то всем элементам массива автоматически присваиваются значения по умолчанию. Например, для числовых значений начальное значение будет `0`. Для массива типа `boolean` начальное значение будет равно `false`, для массива типа char - `'\u0000'`, для массива типа класса (объекты) - `null`. У вас - числовое значение. Значит будет верно сказать, что `(x[0] == 0)` даст `true`.

Comment: То есть в этой строке x[0] = 0, но не null

Comment: да, можете легко это проверить: `int[] x = new int[25]; System.out.println(x[0]);`

Comment: `null` может быть только у объектов, у вас массив из примитивов.